# Tutorial: Intro to React - Rerendering the whole collection instead of the most recently changed element

Tags: reactjs, dom, rendering, react-dom

I have been going through the official "[Tutorial: Intro to React](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)"

The complete code can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR?editors=0010)

A board of nine squares is provided. The state of the squares is "lifted up" into the Game class to minimize the amount of stateful components. Clicking on a square will change the state in said Game class. What I observed is that now every square gets rerendered instead of just the one I clicked.

In order to grasp the problem I counted the number of calls to the return-function of the Square functional component.

The lines of code in question:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

function Square(props) {
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
            {props.value}
        </button>
    );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
    renderSquare(i) {
        return (
            <Square
                value={this.props.squares[i]}
                onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(0)}
                    {this.renderSquare(1)}
                    {this.renderSquare(2)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(3)}
                    {this.renderSquare(4)}
                    {this.renderSquare(5)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(6)}
                    {this.renderSquare(7)}
                    {this.renderSquare(8)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
            xIsNext: true,
        };
    }

    handleClick(i) {
        const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
        squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
        this.setState({
            squares: squares,
            xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
        });
    }

    render() {
        const squares = this.state.squares

        return (
            <div className="game">
                <div className="game-board">
                    <Board
                        squares={squares}
                        onClick={i => this.handleClick(i)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Game from './Game';

ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

I expected react would rerender only the square I clicked.

Instead all nine squares get rerendered after each click on any of the free squares.

In my understanding of react one of the beneficial features is the virtual DOM with it's ability to decide which nodes need to be updated on the "real" DOM. Isn't the whole purpose of 'state' to calculate which part of the screen has to be rerendered?

I realize that when I change the state of "Game" the whole "game component" will be rerendered. But isnt that exactly what should be avoided? How can I minimize the amount of stateful components and still have good performance? In this case its only 9 squares that rerender. But imagine I had a field of 200x200 squares...

Comment: When you have lots of similar elements to be rendered, using `key` property helps get rid of a lot of these rerenders. 

If that doesn't solve the problem, you can make your Square component a PureComponent or a normal Component and write your own implementation of shouldComponentUpdate method, where you can tell react when to render the component.

Comment: @MukeshSoni thank you! I tried assigning a key to each <Square .../> in the renderSquare method in the Board class. Didn't help the case. It would be very helpful for me if you could implement the shouldComponentUpdate for this example. Will dig into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this implementation of `Square` with `shouldComponentUpdate`

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.value !== nextProps.value;
  }

  render() {
    const { value, onClick } = this.props;

    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={onClick}>
        {value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Such little change, so much effect. You just let the magic happen. :) Now I am happy with react again!

Comment: This is an optimization technique which most react users should not have to think about. I don't know why react is rendering all the squares on every render in the first implementation too. Virtual DOM diffing should have figured out that nothing changed for those components. Will look more into it.

Comment: It's irritating that this is not part of the introduction tutorial. Imo they should at least discuss drawbacks of this implementation (as to performance).

Comment: It's not there because the assumption is that virtual DOM diffing will take care of most of these performance problems and most developers should not have to worry about it at all. The more worrying part is that it rerenders every time for such simple DOM structure.